# How can I read XSD data in my c# and print to console? And there is import tag with Schemalocation so how can I import that in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

I have one XSD file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:njdot="SomeURL" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="SomeURL">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.opengis.net/gml" schemaLocation="SomeURL/feature.xsd"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="StudentType">
        <xsd:complexContent>
            <xsd:extension base="gml:AbstractfeatureType">
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="StudentId" nillable="false" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="class_ID" nillable="false" type="xsd:decimal"/>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="1" name="Name" nillable="false" type="xsd:string"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:element name="Student" substitutionGroup="gml:_Feature" type="njdot:StudentType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

My requirement is : Read this XSD data into c# on flying and Print them to console.
Currently while compiling XSD, I am getting following error:

Undefined complexType 'http://www.opengis.net/gml:AbstractFeatureType' is used as a base for complex type extension.

Error: Reference to undeclared substitution group affiliation.

I think I am not importing the external schema which is given with 
Can anyone suggest what can be the solution or how can I achieve my desired output?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your code please

Comment: We can't tell you why code we cannot see isn't working as you expect. Please provide your actual code in the form of a [mre] that demonstrates the issue, as is required by the site guidelines. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.